# pd.DataFrame how to calculate mean() while ignore 'NA' string in some cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe that I want to calculate column mean of A and B,
some rows in A and B are of string 'NA', and others are of numpy.float64
how to calculate the column A and B while ignoring those 'NA'?
I tried to set numeric_only=True then it only return me column C and id.
i'm expecting A and B mean to be 6.6 and 2.6

fruit = pd.DataFrame({'id':(1,2,3,4,5,6),'Name':('apple','apple','melon','melon','orange','orange'), 'A': (1,2,'NA',20,5,5), 'B': (1,5,4,2,'NA',1) , 'C': (1,5,4,2,3,1)})

| id | Name | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | apple | 2 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | melon | 'NA' | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | melon | 20 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | orange | 5 | 'NA' | 3 |
| 6 | orange | 5 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

fruit.replace('NA', np.nan, inplace=True)
fruit['A'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) can skip NaN values, you can use [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and set `errors="coerce"` :

> errors{‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’
>
> - If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
> - **If `coerce`, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN.**
> - If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.

```
fruit[["A", "B"]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce").mean()
```

Output :

```
A    6.6
B    2.6
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
fruit['A'].replace('NA', 0).sum() / sum(fruit['A'].ne('NA'))
# 6.6

fruit['B'].replace('NA', 0).sum() / sum(fruit['B'].ne('NA'))
# 2.6
```

So :

```py
fruit[['A', 'B']].apply(lambda c:c.replace('NA', 0).sum() / sum(c.ne('NA')))
A    6.6
B    2.6
dtype: float64
```